# Aria2c input file problem

Tags: unix

i'am trying to download files with aria2c

Input file

```
 http://aria2.net/files/stable/aria2-1.9.5/aria2-1.9.5.tar.bz2
    dir=/file/old
    out=aria2.old.tar.bz2
  http://aria2.net/files/stable/aria2-1.10.0/aria2-1.10.0.tar.bz2
    out=aria2.new.tar.bz2
```

Run with command

```
aria2c -i task.txt
```

And recieve

```
2011-08-23 12:23:14 ERROR - Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: dir=/file/old

2011-08-23 12:23:14 ERROR - Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: out=aria2.old.tar.bz2

2011-08-23 12:23:14 ERROR - Unrecognized URI or unsupported protocol: out=aria2.new.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use *spaces*, and not tabs at the start of your `dir` and `out` options. (Tabs are used by `aria2c` to specify alternate URLs for [multi-connection downloading](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/aria2/wiki/UsageExample#InputFile).)

Check for tabs by running `awk`:

```
awk "/\t/" task.txt
```

Comment: @Danzan: Sorry, unless you're running a version much lower than 1.12.1, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Danzan: You can go over to the `aria2c` [forum](http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/aria2/index.php) or [bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=159897&atid=813673). Or you can try [Super User](http://superuser.com/).